# WPF datagrid event handle in the edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

i found a very decent [auto-complete textbox control](https://intellibox.codeplex.com/),  it works perfect as i need. but there is only one issue that am trying to resolve that for a month.

it works well in the normal form as auto-complete control, but not working inside the grid.

the issue is when the auto complete pops up we need to **double click the item to select**. But inside the grid we do double click to enter the Edit mode, int the edit template when the control pops up, **on the first click the grid is closing the edit mode**, so the control cant handle the doubleclick, any way to byepass the event to control instead of closing the grid edit mode

i have attached a very neat and **Ready to run** sample to illustrate this issue, it will be helpful if some experts look into it.

Thanks

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OtkpYGX9qfaEYzMEE3RjVQbEU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

have no idea why the TextBlock doesn't act the same as the "Name Picker" control but why wont you just replace the Datagrid's TextBlock with the "Name Picker"?

I tried it and it works as expected:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Infrastructure"
             xmlns:View="clr-namespace:SampleApp.View"
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:SampleApp.ViewModel"          
             xmlns:SampleApp="clr-namespace:SampleApp" 
    x:Class="SampleApp.View.FormControl"          
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type ViewModel:MainViewModel}}" d:DesignWidth="541.198" d:DesignHeight="402.384">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LabelTextBlockStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="0,0,10,0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <View:NamePicker Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,162,0" WatermarkText="Type 'a' key to search"
                 Grid.Row="1" x:Name="autoName" AutoSelectSingleResult="True" 
                 SelectedText="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        </View:NamePicker>

        <!--<View:NamePicker Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,10,0" 
                 Grid.Row="1" x:Name="autoNamea"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>-->

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="First Name"
            Style="{StaticResource LabelTextBlockStyle}"
            Margin="0,5,10,0"/>
        <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList,Mode=TwoWay}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,24,0,-161" Grid.Row="6" Height="141" Width="371">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <View:NamePicker SelectedText="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" WatermarkText="Type 'a' key to Search"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <View:NamePicker VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" WatermarkText="Type 'a' key to search"
                                                                          SelectedText="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            </View:NamePicker>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,34,0,-151" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="181" Width="61"><Run Text="Data Grid"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="Double click on the first row to edit the item (intellibox control in the Grid in Name Column)"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,211,0,-219" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Once you type the 'a' you can choose down arrow key to select the item. it works. but when we use mouse to select the item its not binding the selected item in the GRID, in the first click the event goes to the grid and closing the popup. Any way to prevent this??" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Height="73"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="339,9,14,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Intellibox Control" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,7,0,0" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="The Custom control works well in the noraml form, but not working in the datagrid" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,308,0,-240" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SelectedItem:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,308,0,-220" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>



    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: ya it was a great idea to resolve this, my current solution to resolve this issue is okay, but i have few other columns in the grid, want to do editing only in the Grid edit mode, and thanks for the valuable feedback

Comment: i meant that we have cell template and cell editing template in the DataGrid. when we click/double click the cell it will enter into the Edit mode to load the cell editing template, to load our editors

Comment: and that template is targeting to a TextBlock?

Comment: Yes, the selected property is binded to the textblock in the cell template

Comment: I haven't broke your binding just changed the control type in your template. Have you tried the code i posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69937/discussion-between-spen-d-and-sag1v).